# Why is a Required * path parameter {namespace} getting detected by Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-net

My .Net MVC project has the below ApiController:

[image]

But the Swagger UI generates two methods:

[image]

Observe that the ActionName **TestMethod1** is omitted(probably because there is only one HttpGet in this controller)

Comment: There must be something else, the code you show here should not cause that issue, create a new project that can reproduce this and paste a link I would be happy to look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the DefaultRoute not having the {action} in the path.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Addon", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

It should be like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Addon", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```